# How do you add a Squirrel SQL alias for an Oracle 10g database?

Tags: oracle10g, squirrel-sql

I am trying to create an Add Alias within Squirrel DB for Oracle.  Does anyone have a sample of how to make this Alias work?  I just need some pointers.

Comment: Figured it out, you need to manually set the JDBC driver for the Oracle Thin Driver prior to being able to set up the connection string.

First you need to source the appropriate Driver, then set it up within Squirrel SQL.

Once the driver is set and displays the green check mark, you can set up the Alias.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an Add Alias, you need to ensure that the JDBC driver that will be used has been appropriately set up.  You can tell that a JDBC driver is set up by the Green Check Mark that appears next to it in the Drivers window.

The Oracle Thin Driver could be set up to connect to an Oracle DB.  I've downloaded and configured the ojdbc6-11g.jar by selecting Oracle Thin Driver in the Drivers Window and then selecting Modify.  I added an Extra Class Path that points to the location to ojdbc6-11g.jar itself.

Once the driver is set up, I went ahead and added the Alias using the appropriate connection string information.  Now I am able to access my Oracle DB within Squirrel SQL.